# c++ How to pass an rvalue Reference to another function

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics, move-constructor

I'm using the embedded templated library with `etl::queue`

https://www.etlcpp.com/queue.html

the `etl::queue` is quitvalent to `std::queue`

In order to avoid copying I'd like to actually move the element into the queue.

Now my setup looks like this

```
  bool CETLConcurrentQueue<ElementType_T, u32QueueSize>::Add(ElementType_T &&element, const uint32_t u32Timeout)
{
   //lock mutex...
   queue.push(element);
   //do further stuff
}
```

Now I'm not using `queue.push(std::move(element));` because element is allready an rvalue Reference

However, `queue.push(element);` calls elements copy constructor (which is deleted)
How can I call elements move constructor instead?

Comment: A named variable is never an rvalue reference. The parameter indicates that it will bind to r-value references when called. But you need to convert a named value to an r-value reference by calling `std::move()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use `std::move` to convert `element` to rvalue. As a named variable `element` itself is an lvalue, even its type is an rvalue reference.

```
queue.push(std::move(element));
```

Note that types and [value categories](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category) are two independent things.

(emphasis mine)

> Each C++ expression (an operator with its operands, a literal, a variable name, etc.) is characterized by **two independent properties: a *type* and a *value category***.
>
> ...
>
> The following expressions are lvalue expressions:
>
> - the name of a variable, a function`, a template parameter object (since C++20)`, or a data member, regardless of type, such as `std::cin`
>     or `std::endl`. **Even if the variable's type is rvalue reference, the
>     expression consisting of its name is an lvalue expression**;